# Change code from local file saving to NSUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have this code which calls and saves a function ViewLeft or ViewRight. When you restart the application selected view is loaded.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewLeft.h"
#import "ViewRight.h"

@implementation ViewController

-(IBAction)submitL:(id)sender {
    str = @"L";
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *localloc = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/localinfo.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *local = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:localloc];
    if(!local) {
        local = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else {
        local = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:local];
    };
    [local addObject:str];
    if(![local writeToFile:localloc atomically:NO]) {
        NSLog(@"f1");
    };
    ViewLeft *view = [[ViewLeft alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewLeft" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:view animated:NO completion:nil];
}

-(IBAction)submitR:(id)sender {
    str = @"R";
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *localloc = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/localinfo.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *local = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:localloc];
    if(!local) {
        local = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    } else {
        local = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:local];
    };
    [local addObject:str];
    if(![local writeToFile:localloc atomically:NO]) {
        NSLog(@"f2");
    };
    ViewRight *view = [[ViewRight alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewRight" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:view animated:NO completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.


    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    if (! [defaults objectForKey:@"firstRun"]) {
    [defaults setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"firstRun"];
}
```

And this is the code in AppDelegate.m to select the appropriate view controller:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *localloc = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/localinfo.plist"];
    NSMutableArray *local = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:localloc];
    if(!local) {
        self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    } else {
        local = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:local];
        if([[local objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"L"]){
            self.ViewLeft = [[ViewLeft alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewLeft" bundle:nil];
            self.window.rootViewController = [[ViewLeft alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewLeft" bundle:nil];
        }
        if([[local objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"R"]){
            self.ViewRight = [[ViewRight alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewRight" bundle:nil];
            self.window.rootViewController = [[ViewRight alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewRight" bundle:nil];
        }
    };
    
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    
    return YES;
}
```

Could somebody tell me what code would it be just with usage of function NSUserDefault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` is a simple key-value store. Without getting too advanced, you'd use it as so:

```
-(IBAction)submitR:(id)sender {
    [self saveSubmission:@"R"];
    ViewRight *view = [[ViewRight alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewRight" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:view animated:NO completion:nil];
}

-(IBAction)submitL:(id)sender {
    [self saveSubmission:@"L"];
    ViewLeft *view = [[ViewLeft alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewLeft" bundle:nil];
    [self presentViewController:view animated:NO completion:nil];
}

-(void)saveSubmission:(NSString*)submission { 
    NSUserDefaults* standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [standardDefaults setObject:submission forKey:@"leftRightSubmission"];

    // Not always needed, this flushes changes to disk asap. Can be costly
    [standardDefaults synchronize];
}
```

And in your app delegate:

```
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

NSUserDefaults* standardDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

NSString* lastSubmission = [standardDefaults objectForKey:@"leftRightSubmission"];
if(!lastSubmission) {
    self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
} 
else {
    if([lastSubmission] isEqualToString:@"L"]){
        self.ViewLeft = [[ViewLeft alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewLeft" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = [[ViewLeft alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewLeft" bundle:nil];
    }
    if([lastSubmission isEqualToString:@"R"]){
        self.ViewRight = [[ViewRight alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewRight" bundle:nil];
        self.window.rootViewController = [[ViewRight alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewRight" bundle:nil];
    }
};

[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

return YES;
```

Comment: I tested this code but not saved selected ViewLeft or ViewRight when I start application second time. What I must change? (P.S. don't worry its not my homework)

Comment: Modified solution. It wasn't working because you always referenced the first object in the array (`[local objectAtIndex:0]`), but when you were saving, you added it to the end of the array via `addObject`. As such, I've got rid of the array all together, I don't think you needed it. If you do, then use the array as before with NSUserDefaults, but in app delegate use `[[local lastObject] isEqualToString:@""]`

Comment: Work! Thanks for the help! Tom